# PYTHON MYSQL INSERT ONE SINGLE VALUE

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

This is not working any id why?
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): Synthax error near '%s)' at line 1

insert into a 2 fields table with a autoincrement key
I just try to insert value

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  port=3306,
  user="**",
  passwd="******",
  database="db1"
)


mycursor = mydb.cursor()


sql = "INSERT INTO t_user (name) VALUES (%s)"
val = ('test')

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```

Thank you

Comment: `('test')` is not a tuple. Try `('test',)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement parameters are usually passed as a tuple. If you want to make a tuple with one element, the syntax is

```
val = ('test',)
```

If you miss the comma, then `val` will just hold the string `'test'`, which won't work as your statement parameters.